# Sending a file path through android client to local python server

Tags: android, python

I want to send a file (audio) path (that file is located on android device) to my local python server. I want my server to read that file from the client.
Is there any suitable way to do that , I am struck !!
Thank you

Comment: use loopj library you can easily send files in the android File class, as for python i don't know that part

Comment: from android you push the file stream to the server.

Comment: danny117 can you please explain through example

Comment: stream like input or output ? but they are in binary format , what have to be done to make them decode what the were at client?